# ASCII Raster format cellsize

Tags: elevation

I have a particular .asc file, with elevation data in it.
I am wondering if somebody knows, what is the unit for the "cellsize" variable in the header of the .asc file?

Here is how the header looks like:

```
ncols   236
nrows   121
xllcorner   2.022083333
yllcorner   41.32875
cellsize    0.000833333
NODATA_value    -32768
```

What unit is the "0.000833333"?
A meter, or an arc?

I found a [couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid) of [pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ESRI_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/) on internet which explain the content of the .asc files headers, but still none explain what is the length unit of the "cellsize"?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly not meters. 0.00083m is tiny, less than 1mm.

At the equator, 0.00083 degrees is around 90m, which sounds about right for a lot of the more usual DEMs (such as SRTM, GTOPO). This varies according to latitude.

```
1/0.00083 is roughly 1200 pixels per degree
divide again by 60 - 1200/60 = 20 pixels per arc minute
divide again by 60 - 20/60 = 1 pixel every 3 arc seconds (.33 pixels per arc second)
```

So it's probably a 3 arc-second DEM (like the original SRTM). You should probably check with your source for what projection they're using too

Comment: Thank you Steven.
The .asc file has been downloaded from:
http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/gridsphere/gridsphere?cid=geonlidar&format=sd
I didn't checked it previously - it's a 3 arc second. Thank you.

How could I determine how much is that "0.000833333" in meters, based on latitude, or any other information?

Comment: there's a [handy online calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html) you can use. Your raster covers latitudes 41.32875  to 41.429583293, an area covering Barcelona. If you use a GIS you can project to an appropriate local projection (e.g. epsg:2062) in meters, and can use measuring tools to check distances in meters.

Comment: Thank you Steven.
Looks like a single arc-second = 30.87 * cos(latitude) meters.
3 arc-second are then 3 * 30.87 * cos(latitude).
This means that the length of my cell would be: 0.000833333 * 3 * 30.87 * cos(41.32875) = 0.058 meters, so 5.8 centimeters??
Did I get that right?

Comment: that doesn't look right ;) I plugged in 41.32875 into latitude on that form. This says that a degree of longitude is 83715.723 m at that latitude (83.7km). You have 1200 pixels per degree (1/0.000833333), so a pixel is 83715.72/1200.0 = 69.76 m in the horizontal. :)

Comment: Thank you Steve. Just one more question, and I won't bother you any more: this "cellsize" of 0.000833333 degrees, is the length of the bottom horizontal edge of the cell? Not top?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the original answer - there are no standard units that `cellsize` has to conform to. The units are only required to be same as those for the coordinate system used to define the lower left corner (`xllcorner`/`yllcorner`). Meters would be 'valid' units for UTM, for example.

https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000421.shtml